# Can I keep my Boot Camp partition when moving to a larger hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, startup, partition

I just bought a 512 GB hard drive to replace my 250 GB hard drive, which currently has a Boot Camp partition (pretty vanilla, just running a standard Windows 7 install). I was planning to just clone the hard drive using SuperDuper or Carbon Copy, but will Boot Camp's existence make this problematic? Asking because I'm not sure how the extra 250 GB will be allocated. Should I just uninstall Boot Camp, delete the partition, copy over my Yosemite partition, and then reinstall Boot Camp?

Comment: SD & CCC will clone the Mac partition [to a different size, no worries] but you will need WinClone to do the Bootcamp. I've never done it myself, my Bootcamp is on a separate drive so my HD>SSD was painless with only CCC, but that's the accepted wisdom.

Comment: Welcome, wish you luck